# What is this uid file in com.google.android.youtube

Tags: huawei, file-management, youtube

I found this file in my father's Huawei Y9 2019,the path of this file is

Phone > Android > data> Com.google.android.youtube > files > offline > (Random alphabet and number folder) > stream

This file's name has random alphabet and number and file extension is "UID"

Ex. Xxxxhhhhfghh11233bb.uid

This file is 0kb.

I don't know if this file related with YouTube download or not but my father never used YouTube download function before.

I want to ask if someone ever found this file or know what it is.

Thank you.